# How to make a dropdown CSS animation for custom select?

Tags: css, animation, select, drop-down-menu

I'm making a [custom select](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp) with javascript. The problem is, I want to make it that when you click on the select box, the options should **drop down**, not just appear.

The project is pretty big (probably could be a lot smaller but I'm trying to do this as much as I can on my own), so I'm going to only leave a little bit of the code (let me know if you need more, I'll be happy to put it up).

Here is the flow of making the options appear:

When clicking on the select box, it adds a CSS class to the element containing the options that makes it `display: block;`.

Here is the CSS class of the select box itself:

```
.custom-select-outer-box {
    width: 100%; /* of its wrapper */
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    user-select: none;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

And here is the code for the "options" element:

```
.custom-select-options {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

And finally, the CSS class I add to it when clicking the select box:

```
.custom-select-show {
    display: block;
}
```

The thing is I don't want it to be just a `display: block;` because then it just apears. I want it to slide down.

I've tried making a CSS animation that's something like this:

```
@keyframes slide-down {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(-200px); /* this height brings it to the exact position for the drop down */
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
```

But when adding it like this, the drop down is visible before even making it down. like  [this](https://pro.panopto.com/Panopto/Pages/Viewer.aspx?tid=c83e3210-9962-4b06-bf26-ad880175775d).

I hope to get an answer as soon as possible and let me know if I left any information out or was not clear enough.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're going to make your own dropdown control then you will also need to make it accessible: https://css-tricks.com/striking-a-balance-between-native-and-custom-select-elements/

Comment: Accessible from where?

Comment: Accessible to screenreaders and people with vision and physical challenges. Read about accessibility compliance here: https://www.w3.org/WAI/standards-guidelines/wcag/

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use translateY because you changing your list position on the screen. When a list is hidden set the height to a minimum or zero and then when the user will click the button the list will "roll down" to the defined height.

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("list-roll-down").classList.toggle("is-active");
}
```

```css
#list-roll-down{
width: 200px;
height: 20px;
background-color: green;
opacity: 0.2;
  transition: all .4s;
}
#list-roll-down.is-active{
  height: 150px;
opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>
<div id="list-roll-down"></div>
```

Comment: Except that I used the `max-height` property instead of `height`.